# How can I add a written question to an existing collectives on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, collectives

How do I add a written question to an existing collective (e.g. Google Cloud) on Stack Overflow?

Assume I asked a question before which is not on Google Cloud collective now I'm going to add that to it.

Comment: Collectives are bound by tags, not when the question was posted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question being part of a collective is determined by the tags it has. If a tag belongs to a collective, then the question belongs in the collective.

Therefore, in order to *add* an existing question to a collective, you need to add a tag to it.

[See the full list of Google Cloud Collective tags here.](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=tags)

Do make sure the tag belongs on the question. If the question is not part of a collective now it means that from its initial posting to now none of the relevant tags was used. It is impossible to say whether it was because the tag was inappropriate just overlooked, so remember to ensure it does apply.